# Cannot for the life of me understand where the mistake is in query

Tags: mysql, sql

getting this error:

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'rMin left join select * from  ( ( select  symbol,(dt) as dt,callPut,bid,ask,stri' at line 15
```

on the following query:

```
            select * from (
            select * from 
            (
            (
            select 
            symbol,(dt) as dt,callPut,bid,ask,strike,maturity,`Open Int`,impVol,theta,delta from bats.Opt where impVol>0 
            ) as a1
            inner join
            (select 
            symbol,min(dt) as dt from bats.Opt where impVol>0 
            group by symbol
            ) as b1
            on a1.symbol=b1.symbol and a1.dt=b1.dt 
            )
            as rMin
            left join
            select * from 
            (
            (
            select 
            symbol,(dt) as dt,callPut,bid,ask,strike,maturity,`Open Int`,impVol,theta,delta from bats.Opt where impVol>0 
            ) as a1
            inner join
            (select 
            symbol,max(dt) as dt from bats.Opt where impVol>0 
            group by symbol
            ) as b1
            on a1.symbol=b1.symbol and a1.dt=b1.dt 
            )
            as rMax

            on rMax.symbol=rMin.symbol
            )
```

Comment: sql in line 6, remove `()` from dt

Comment: Format your sql better and You will not have such problems. You lack select statement on 3rd level of nesting. And outer select is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by formatting the query so you can read it easily, matching parentheses and so on.

Then, I would run each subquery to be sure they are syntactically correct.

But, before doing that, I'd put a table alias after the last closing parentheses.  MySQL requires subqueries in the `from` clause to have table aliases.  Admittedly, the error for this is the more descriptive "Every derived table must have its own alias", so this might not solve the entire problem.